# Find m numbers that sum to n in a sequence

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

Given a sequence from *1 to n*, I want to find all the *unique* subsequences of size *m* that sum up to *n*. The subsequences don't need to be contiguous. For example

```
if m = 2, n = 5
The possible unique subsequences of size 2 are {1,4} and {2,3}
```

So far I've been able to generate all the subsequences using recursion but my code is not returning only the unique subsequences, there are some duplicates in the result.

```
function allCombinations(m, n) {
if (m < 1) {
    return [];
}

let helper = function(m, n, arr, result, index){
    if (n < 0 || m < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (m === 0 && n === 0) {
        result.push(arr.slice());
        return 1;
    }

    for (let i = index; i <= n; i++){
        arr.push(i);
        helper(m - 1, n - i, arr, result, index + 1);
        arr.pop();
    }

}

let result = [];
helper(m, n, [], result, 0);

return result;
}
```

and when calling with

```
let res = allCombinations(2, 5);
```

the result is

```
[ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 2 ] ]
```

and as you can see {3,2} is a duplicate of {2,3}. How can I change my code so it returns only the unique sequences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce that the next pick is greater than the current one by calling the recursive helper function with `i` instead of `index`:

```
for (let i = index; i <= n; i++){
    arr.push(i);
    helper(m - 1, n - i, arr, result, i + 1);
    arr.pop();
}
```

This will yield unique sequences where the elements are sorted in ascending order. If you call it with just `i`, you allow duplicate picks.

Changing this will allow zero as pick unless you call the helper with index 1 from the wrapper function:

```
let result = [];
helper(m, n, [], result, 1);
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, I knew it had something to do with the index but couldn't find what the issue was. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const res = allCombinations(2, 5);

const unique = res.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   const exists = acc.some(item => item.sort().toString() === curr.sort().toString());

   return exists ? acc : [...acc, curr]; 
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I was actually avoiding filtering out the result but this for sure will work with the code I have

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend generators for this kind of problem -

1. find solutions from `1..n`
2. of size `m`
3. where `q` is the target sum, initialised to `n`

```js
function* solve(n, m, q = n)
{ if (m == 0 && q == 0)
    yield []
  else if (n == 0 || q < 0)
    return
  else
  { for (const s of solve(n - 1, m - 1, q - n))
      yield [...s, n]
    yield *solve(n - 1, m, q)
  }
}

for (const p of solve(5, 2))
  console.log(p)

// [1,4]
// [2,3]
```

We can collapse the `for` loop above by using another default argument for the solution, `s` -

```js
function* solve(n, m, q = n, s = [])             // s = []
{ if (m == 0 && q == 0)
    yield s
  else if (n == 0 || q < 0)
    return
  else
  { yield *solve(n - 1, m - 1, q - n, [n, ...s]) // update s
    yield *solve(n - 1, m, q, s)                 // pass s
  }
}

for (const p of solve(5, 2))
  console.log(p)

// [1,4]
// [2,3]
```

And we can collapse the `if` statements using early `return` -

```js
function* solve(n, m, q = n, s = [])
{ if (m == 0 && q == 0) return yield s  // <-
  if (n == 0 || q < 0) return
  yield *solve(n - 1, m - 1, q - n, [n, ...s])
  yield *solve(n - 1, m, q, s)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(solve(5,2))))
// [[1,4],[2,3]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(solve(9,3))))
// [[1,2,6],[1,3,5],[2,3,4]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(solve(27,6))))
// [[1,2,3,4,5,12],[1,2,3,4,6,11],[1,2,3,4,7,10],[1,2,3,5,6,10],[1,2,3,4,8,9],[1,2,3,5,7,9],[1,2,4,5,6,9],[1,2,3,6,7,8],[1,2,4,5,7,8],[1,3,4,5,6,8],[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
```

If you don't like the extra parameters on `solve`, we can use an inner `loop` -

```js
function solve(n, m)
{ function* loop(n, m, q, s)                   // "helper"
  { if (m == 0 && q == 0) return yield s
    if (n == 0 || q < 0) return
    yield *loop(n - 1, m - 1, q - n, [n, ...s])
    yield *loop(n - 1, m, q, s)
  }
  return loop(n, m, n, [])                     // n, m, q = n, s = []
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(solve(5,2))))
// [[1,4],[2,3]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(solve(9,3))))
// [[1,2,6],[1,3,5],[2,3,4]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(solve(27,6))))
// [[1,2,3,4,5,12],[1,2,3,4,6,11],[1,2,3,4,7,10],[1,2,3,5,6,10],[1,2,3,4,8,9],[1,2,3,5,7,9],[1,2,4,5,6,9],[1,2,3,6,7,8],[1,2,4,5,7,8],[1,3,4,5,6,8],[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
```

If you don't like that it exposes the generator, you can return all results using `Array.from` -

```js
function solve(n, m)
{ function* loop(n, m, q, s)
  { if (m == 0 && q == 0) return yield s
    if (n == 0 || q < 0) return
    yield *loop(n - 1, m - 1, q - n, [n, ...s])
    yield *loop(n - 1, m, q, s)
  }
  return Array.from(loop(n, m, n, []))   // Array.from
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(solve(5,2)))  // solve now returns array
// [[1,4],[2,3]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(solve(9,3)))  // <-
// [[1,2,6],[1,3,5],[2,3,4]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(solve(27,6))) // <-
// [[1,2,3,4,5,12],[1,2,3,4,6,11],[1,2,3,4,7,10],[1,2,3,5,6,10],[1,2,3,4,8,9],[1,2,3,5,7,9],[1,2,4,5,6,9],[1,2,3,6,7,8],[1,2,4,5,7,8],[1,3,4,5,6,8],[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
```

Mix and match any of these techniques to your heart's content!